# How to intent and move to fragment in notifications?

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

I am doing an android application and I want my app to intent to the `notifications_fragment` when the notification was clicked. But I don't know how to make it. I am using this code:

```
private void getNotification(String notificationTitle, String notificationBody, String clickAction) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(clickAction);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.putExtra("title", notificationTitle);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "my_channel_id_01";

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "My Notifications", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);

            notificationChannel.setDescription(notificationTitle);
            notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
            notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
            notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{0, 1000, 500, 1000});
            notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
        }

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.mini_icon)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplication().getResources(), R.drawable.clustore_logo_108dp))
                .setTicker("From: Clustore")
                .setContentTitle(notificationTitle)
                .setContentText(notificationBody)
                .setContentInfo("Clustore")
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri);

        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
```

Comment: what is clickAction ?

Comment: it was the data for `<action android:name="OPEN_NOTIFICATION_ACTIVITY" />`.

Comment: clickAction = OPEN_NOTIFICATION_ACTIVITY. Which was correspond to `<action android:name="com.dreamakers.coonna.Activity_OPEN_NOTIFICATION_ACTIVITY" />` in Manifest file

Answer (score 0):

**Use Pending Intent in Your Brodcast Reciver file**

```
  PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, rId,
            notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    mNotifyManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    build = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
    build.setContentTitle(rTitle)
            .setContentText(rDesc)
            .setChannelId(rId+"")
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle())
            .setCustomContentView(notificationLayout)
            .setCustomBigContentView(notificationLayoutExpanded)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_calendar);
```